# Magento 2.4 - Programmatically Created Categories in Multi-Store Collide

Tags: category, magento2.4, multistore, url, url-rewrite

I have a Magento 2.4.3 multi-store and I am currently creating categories programmatically, with the following code:

```
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category',
    ['data' =>
        ["name" => $refCat['name'],
         "is_active" => $refCat['active'],
         "include_in_menu" => $refCat['menu'],
         "parent_id" => $parentID,
         "store_id" => $refCat['store_id']
        ]
    ]);
$category->setCustomAttributes(["display_mode" => "PRODUCTS",
    "custom_use_parent_settings" => true,
    "is_anchor" => "1"]);

$repository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
$repository->save($category);
```

Unfortunately, I am unable create categories with the same name, example "Brands", even if they are assigned to different store ids, as I get the following error: *Could not save category: URL key for specified store already exists.*

After reviewing the URL_Rewrite table, I found that the entries for any store created  using the above method have a store_id value of 1, regardless of what value was passed assigned when the category was created.

What am I missing?